# Is there a way to trigger a glue job directly from SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I'm looking to trigger a glue job from SNS without using Lambda. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible

Comment: Do you require SNS? There are other ways to asynchronously start a glue job—though they all require some sort of intermediary component.